# Preview Link Generation - Spring Boot React Application - Social Media Share

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, meta-tags, social-media

**Requirement:**

- To share/post the progress of the application to social media (Twitter, Facebook)

**Acceptance Criteria:**

- When user shares/posts the link, it should preview the image of the progress in the social media post.

**Tools and Technologies:**

- Spring Boot REST for services
- React Js for front-end development

**Description:**

I have a react application which tracks the progress of the users goals and objectives. The progress is displayed in a card component with progress bar. I need to share this progress component to social media like Twitter, Facebook.

I would like to know how to generate preview links so that I can share that link to twitter, which in turn, should display the progress bar chart component as an image/thumbnail view on the social media platform.

**What I have tried so far:**

I have created an api which extracts the meta tags when we pass the url link. The reference image is below,
[image]

I really don't know how to add meta tags to my react component. I have researched on react-helmet npm package, but, I have no idea on how to generate an image out of react-component, make the image as a link and create a **preview link url** for that, so that it can be shared to social media.

The component which I would like to post on social media is,
[image]

I'm working on it for the past couple of days, have not got any helpful information so far, as I'm new to the react front-end technology.

It would be highly appreciated if anyone of you could help me in this regard.

Thanks a lot for your time.

**Note**: I apologize if my post is not as per rules and regulations of Stackoverflow, I'm open for corrections. Thanks.